# Why am I receiving a Critical Asset Compiler Error when I try to add an asset in XCode?

Tags: compiler-errors, xcode13

I have ben running into the "**Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code**" error with every attempt of adding assets to my xcode app. Whenever I add an asset from the initially empty "Asset Catalog" and try running - even if the asset is not called for in my ContentView code - this error occurs.  I have tried a variety of fixes listed online, I've deleted the "Derived Data" folder, tried restarting my computer, removing added assets, restarting the project from scratch, etc. I have restarted multiple times in hopes of catching a simple miss, but after retrying ~7 times I am wondering if it is something more fundamental that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the attributes of the files before adding to your assets...

```
cd yourfolder
xattr -rc .
```

It's also a "good housekeeping" task for your project folder too!